# What are Angularjs promise states?

Tags: angularjs

beside success, error and then, do $http get rest promise offer more states we can act upon ?
I once logged in the console a raw response that showed these 3 states and more, but don't remember which.

Comment: pretty sad you can't find answer in the docs and let someone else look them up for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the [$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) service extends on the [$q](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q) service. The `$http` has 2 additional methods (success, and error) on top of the existing methods provided by `$q` (given below):

> **.then(successCallback, errorCallback, notifyCallback)** – regardless of when the promise was or will be resolved or rejected, then calls one of the success or error callbacks asynchronously as soon as the result is available. The callbacks are called with a single argument: the result or rejection reason. Additionally, the notify callback may be called zero or more times to provide a progress indication, before the promise is resolved or rejected.
>   This method returns a new promise which is resolved or rejected via the return value of the successCallback, errorCallback. It also notifies via the return value of the notifyCallback method. The promise can not be resolved or rejected from the notifyCallback method.
>
> **.catch(errorCallback)** – shorthand for promise.then(null, errorCallback)
>
> **.finally(callback)** – allows you to observe either the fulfillment or rejection of a promise, but to do so without modifying the final value. This is useful to release resources or do some clean-up that needs to be done whether the promise was rejected or resolved. See the full specification for more information.